# SQLITE - insert ... where - how to force dynamic behaviour

Tags: sqlite, dynamic, insert, where-clause, behavior

I tried INSERT with WHERE condition. Now, the WHERE would depend on each newly inserted record, e.g. `WHERE NOT EXISTS (select ... from <table I am inserting records into>)`.

However, the WHERE clause is evaluated ONCE and does not consider each newly inserted record.

I know about INSERT OR IGNORE, or INSERT OR UPDATE or UPSERT ...
However, in my case, the WHERE clause would be more complex than just verifying existence of the key.

The trouble is that the query optimizer evaluates the WHERE once forever, not considering the newly inserted records one by one. Fair enough.

QUESTION: Is there a way to force the query optimizer to consider each record right after insertion ?

As a (somewhat theoretical) example: Introducing prime numbers from a recursively generated number series, with the WHERE condition stating that it cannot be devided by any of the (prime) numbers already present in the table. The code **WON'T work**; it will introduce the 19 numbers altogether.

```
CREATE TABLE pnumbers (pnumber number primary key);

with r as 
(select 2 as n union all select n+1 as n from r where n < 20)
insert into pnumbers
select n from r where not exists 
(select pnumber from pnumbers pn where r.n % pn.pnumber = 0 );
```

P.S.
On the opposite, the DELETE .. WHERE **works perfectly** and is remarkably fast. Below code eliminates non-prime-numbers out of 10 million consecutive numbers in just 90 seconds on my gaming laptop - (however, this was not the idea):

```sql
delete from pnumbers  where exists (select pnumber from pnumbers pn2 
where pn2.pnumber <= sqrt(pnumbers.pnumber) and pnumbers.pnumber % pn2.pnumber = 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The trouble is that the query optimizer evaluates the WHERE once
> forever

No, this is not true.
The `WHERE` clause is evaluated once for each row of `r`, because the subquery of `EXISTS` is a [correlated subquery](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#correlated_subqueries).

The problem is somewhat different.

In any `INSERT INTO ... SELECT...` statement, the `SELECT...` statement is executed first and after it is finished the result-set returned is inserted into the table.

This means that for your theoretical example, no insertion to the table `pnumbers` will occur before this statement returns:

```
with r as 
(select 2 as n union all select n+1 as n from r where n < 20)
select n from r where not exists 
(select pnumber from pnumbers pn where r.n % pn.pnumber = 0 );
```

Any reference to the table `pnumbers` in the above statement will access an empty table because no rows are inserted yet.
This is why this statement returns all the rows of `r`.

It is true that in the documentation of SQLite's [INSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) this behavior is not clearly outlined, but this is the meaning of:

> A new entry is inserted into the table for each row of data
> **returned** by executing the SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks for your fast and professional answer ! In the meantime, I found an (odd) circumvention - DELETE ... WHERE (see my P.S.).

Comment: @Pelton this DELETE statement has nothing to do with the way `INSERT INTO...SELECT...` works. As I explain in my answer the insertion of the rows occurs **after** the SELECT statement returns all the rows. On the other hand the DELETE statement deletes the rows one by one after examining the conditions in the WHERE clause. This means that after each deletion the EXISTS subquery accesses a different dataset.

Answer (score 0):

While everything said by forpas in his answer is correct, it is possible to solve the problem moving the EXIST condition in a temporary trigger.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TRIGGER primes BEFORE INSERT ON main.pnumbers
WHEN exists (select pn.pnumber from pnumbers pn where NEW.pnumber % pn.pnumber = 0)
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(IGNORE);  
END;

WITH r AS
(select 2 as n union all select n+1 as n from r where n < 20)
insert into pnumbers
select n from r;

DROP TRIGGER primes;
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/WXKHI2-p)

In this example you try to insert every value from 2 to 19, but the trigger will fire, for every row, at the time of the INSERT, when previous rows have already been inserted, and the rows that satisfy the exists condition are never inserted.

You can of course use a normal, permanent, trigger, but a temporary one will only fire when insert are made from the same connection where you defined it, and it won't impact on other potential modifications by other apps on the same table.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, forpas for the scientific answer and Andrea for the technical way to make it work. The trigger solution does the job PERFECTLY, avoiding my lousy DELETE workaround, and is just as fast. You made my day !